# How to version Docker images for upstream software

Tags: docker, openssl, centos

I'm currently building Docker images for an EOL'd platform (don't ask) providing various tools with an up-to-date OpenSSL.

https://github.com/cjolowicz/docker-centos5

What would be the community wisdom about how to tag these images?

There are three bits of information:

- the version of the platform (e.g. Centos 5.11)
- the version of the packaged software (e.g. Curl 7.64.0)
- the version of my Dockerfile

Currently I'm tending to something like `curl-centos5:7.64.0`, thus including the platform in the image name, and using only the upstream version as the tag. I'm not providing any indication about the version of my Dockerfile, i.e. future updates will simply overwrite the existing image on Docker Hub.

My reasoning is that in my case, the platform is quite central (because it's so old), so it should be a part of the image name.

Also, people tend to use tags like `$upstream` or `$upstream-$platform`, omitting the version of their own Dockerfile. On the other hand, distros like Debian usually append a suffix to the upstream version, but this does not seem to be custom in the Docker community.

What's the best, or accepted, way?

Comment: You can use anything that’s meaningful to you.  If the packaged software will (probably) never ever get an update, just using a date stamp as the image tag is pretty reasonable.  I wouldn’t go out of my way to include the distro name in the image name.

Comment: I agree with David's comment. Do what makes sense to you. I would only add this: Try to look at other "professional" images on dockerhub, and see if their tagging logic sparks any idea - for example: https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby